# htaccess is not working good

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I used following to redirect the page.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /mytake/huts(.*) /mytake/surveys/$1
```

and that worked, actually changing URL in address bar which I don't want.

I tried following which is NOT working at all.

```
RewriteRule ^mytake/huts$ mytake/surveys/ [L,R=301]
```

My question is why second line is not working ???

My testing URL is: http://www.mydomain.com/mytake/huts (don't click, take it as test URL :) )

Answer (score 2):

If I understood all that correctly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mytake/huts/(.*)$ mytake/surveys/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Address will stay the same.

P.S.
Run command `a2enmod rewrite` and check the AllowOverride directive in conf file.

Comment: Is there any apache configuration which allows `RedirectMath` But doesn't allow `RewriteRule` ???

Comment: If you're requesting http://.../mytake/huts - it will search for index file in /mytake/huts directory, does it exist?

Comment: `huts` directory doesn't exist that's why I wanna redirect to surveys folder.

Comment: RedirectMatch is in mod_alias module in apache, and all rewriting manipulation commands is in mod_rewrite module, and it could be disabled. What OS are you using?

Comment: Great! That was my first guess. Thanks a lot you for confirmation. BTW its Ubuntu.